# Access request attribute inside struts 2 param tag?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

i want to access request attribute (named 'msg_key') value in `param` tag . It return empty

```
  var message='<s:url attributes..><s:param name="msg_key" value="#request['msg_key']" /></s:url>';
```

though same work in property tag

```
 var message1='<s:property  value="#request['msg_key']" />';
```

i am not getting  how to access request attribute inside param tag?

Comment: Just close the `param` tag properly and it should work.

Comment: Aleksandr M it was typo mistake its already closed. Corrected the OP too

Comment: If it is working in property then it should work in param as well.

Comment: At the very least, consider wrapping OGNL expressions in `%{}`, although it shouldn't matter in this particular case. Also, it'd be best to show what's actually rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var message = '<s:url attributes../>'+'?'+ '<s:property  value="#request['msg_key']" />';
```

or:

```
<s:url var="test" attributes..>
    <s:param name="msg_key" value="#request['msg_key']" />
</s:url>
var message = '<s:property value="#test"/>'
```